# Is a broccoli that already turned yellow anyhow harmful?

Tags: food-safety, broccoli

After I bought a broccoli I placed it into my fridge. Today I rediscovered it and wanted to eat it. Now the crown of the broccoli already turned yellowish (it's actually a yellowish-greenish-brownish color).

Is it still safe to eat the broccoli (after cooking) or are there any health harming issues I should consider before eating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to eat, but it would be fibrous and a bit tough - not to mention that the flavor might be a bit subdued. I would personally cut my loses and toss it in the bin.

Comment: Can you provide any kind of reference for your answer? Either way: thanks a lot!

Comment: If personal experience counts as a reference on the "fibrous and a bit tough...flavor...subdued" part :) As for the safe part, a paper in UC Davis' repo: http://postharvest.ucdavis.edu/libraries/Questions_and_Answers/?uid=107&ds=267

Comment: That's what I was looking for, personal experience, flavoured with a scientific paper reference. Great, thanks! :-)

Comment: Very welcome @GottliebNotschnabel!